# unable to load windows or its drives. Data in those drive is important

Tags: 12.04, boot

I was using Windows 8 on my Dell Inspiron 14z 5423. Then I installed ubuntu from live usb.
While installing, I chose 2nd option(other, (not replace windows 8)). Then it asked create partition. I created & installed ubuntu 12.10 on / directory.
Now I'm can't load windows or its drives. Data in those drive is important. I tried Boot-repair from LinuxSecureRemix. But still not getting loaded.
This is link after doing boot repair utility.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5703933/

Answer (score 2):

From your boot repair report it seems that Ubuntu has replaced Windows. I think your best bet to recover data is to stop using the installed Ubuntu, boot from a live disk, install [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk] and choose the recover partitions option.

- [Testdisk step by step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your log, it can be inferred that you have 2 hard-disks, one 500GB HDD and one 32GB SSD with Windows on it. Ubuntu is installed on the 500GB disk and Windows is still intact.

Try booting in a rescue disk (LinuxSecureRemix) and mount the Windows partition to see if it's been overwritten yet. If it's still there then backup all important data and insert a Windows installer disk to let it try to fix it's boot sequence.

After that, it's highly probable that the Windows installer will have overwritten Ubuntu's bootloader, use the rescue disk to reinstall GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader).